# DYNAMIC HTML (FONT SIZES)

Tags: dhtml

I've written a code that displays 2 buttons and one text. When we click on the button, "GROW" the size of the text should grow and when we click, "SHRINK" the size should reduce. But this is working only for one click. When I click second time, the functions are not invoked. Why is this happening?
Here is the code for it..

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Grow()
        {
            var a=document.getElementById(1);
            a.style.fontSize=a.style.fontSize+50;

        }
        function Shrink()
        {
            var a=document.getElementById(1);
            a.style.fontSize=20;

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="grow" onclick="Grow()">
    <input type="button" value="shrink" onclick="Shrink()">
    <p id="1"> Hello </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you perform the grow action for the first time it automatically uses the units px as you started off with a null value. You will need to parse the value of .fontSize before you can perform arithmetic on it. Try this...

```
parseInt(a.style.fontSize.replace('px', ''));
```

to get a numerical value you can perform arithmetic on.

In full...

```
function Grow()
{
    var a=document.getElementById(1);

    // Get a number we can perform arithmetic on
    size = parseInt(a.style.fontSize.replace('px',''));

    // Additional check needed because original dimensions not specified
    if (!isNaN(size)) { // If we now have a number we can use
        a.style.fontSize=size+50;
    } else { // Otherwise, set to 50 (assuming we are starting from 0px)
        a.style.fontSize=50;
    }
}
```

Comment: But the change is applied for the 1st time only

Comment: My answer will fix your problem. When you grow it the first time, it adds px to the size.

Comment: Friendly hint: If you find an answer has solved your problem, you can help the SO community by marking the answer as accepted. ;) :D